# Should appearance of job hopping be a factor in deciding on a job offer with better benefits?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I got an offer for a job that offers significantly more money money than my current job. I think the work I'm doing at my current job is interesting, and I'm very excited for the working coming up in the next few months. At the same time, the new job opportunity is a good one too, with fun people working on a cool project and offering a tad bit more autonomy/decision making.

However, my resume has just a couple of short duration jobs. The first one was a so-so job, and the second is my current job. I am unable to decide on the job offer as I don't want to be perceived as a "job hopper". I like both my options, and I would be switching mainly for the better pay.

I started my job search because someone in HR hinted I was being paid less than the others on the team. I didn't really negotiate the salary when I took this job, and it left me wondering if I could have asked for more.

Is the appearance of a being a "job hopper" an important factor to consider while deciding on the new job offer? Can I take this job offer to my current manager and ask for a raise?

Comment: why is your last point a confounding factor? Just talk to your manager. They can either afford to keep you on or not. There is nothing wrong with taking a better role.

Comment: Maybe "confounding" isn't quite the right word. It's just something that made me feel like job searching.

Comment: Workplace stack exchange is not for seeking advice. Really though I think this boils down to: how much of a pay raise would it take for you feel like it was worth it to switch even if it doesn't turn out? Every new job has some amount of risk that there's something about it you'll end up hating, whereas the current job you already know you have no major complaints about. So I don't think I'd bother unless it was a not insignificant raise, or if I really needed the money, but that's me.

Comment: Have you tried asking for a raise to get you up to the market rates? You don't need to threaten to quit or wave around a job offer to a for a raise. If you did ask, how did it go?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the appearance of a being a "job hopper" an important factor to consider while deciding on the new job offer?

Decide what is more important to you. Then it will be clear if you should accept or reject the job offer.

- If the money is more important, accept the offer.
- If avoiding the appearance of job hopping is more important, reject the offer and stick around at the current job for a bit longer.

Only you can make this decision.

Do not give undue importance to "sound career advice" coming from "career coaches" or self-declared experts. Such advice is usually too generalized and is based on several assumptions. It doesn't always lead to the correct choice in specific situations.

Rules of the form "always do this" and "never do this" are rarely useful. Despite your "job hopper resume", you have already received a job offer. This is an example of "never be a job hopper" is more of a guideline than a sacrosanct rule. It is most likely a mistake to reject the job offer *only* because "a lot of strangers on the internet said job hopping looks bad."

> Can I take this job offer to my current manager and ask for a raise?

Taking a job offer to your manager to ask for a raise is usually a bad idea. It carries an implicit (or even explicit) threat, "if you don't match this offer, I am leaving." It is also highly unlikely to work in the longer term:

- If they match the offer right away, it implies they could have paid you higher to start with, but were just getting away with paying you lower. Since they don't want to lose face in that manner, they will likely "negotiate" for a lower raise.
- Even if they do match the offer, you will probably get a lower raise than you deserve the next couple of times, because "we just gave him a huge raise the last time." This is especially seen in larger companies where salary raises need multiple levels of approval.

You started your job search because you were unhappy with the salary. This is probably going to be the cause of your unhappiness at the current job in the near future. You need to making your resume look good is worth the trouble of bearing that unhappiness.

Answer (score 3):

You may call it job hopping, or you may call it a fast career progression. Your job switches are fine as long as every change progresses you in your career.

Companies, at least rational companies, don't worry about you leaving for a better offer. If you leave for a better offer, then you were worth more than they are paying, so they benefitted all the time when you worked there. That's where job hopping doesn't hurt.

They worry about people who get bored, who fall out with colleagues, who behave so badly that the company pushes them out after a short time. These employees were not very good employees in the first place, and that's where job hopping hurts.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like setting aside the salary, you like both jobs. You can’t be sure you will like the new job, therefore avoid the risk if you can. You goal should be to stay in the job you have and fix the salary problem.

You should talk to you manager. You should tell him how much you enjoy your job. 
However, explain that you believe you are underpaid and it is making unhappy there. Be prepared to present your case with evidence of your contribution to the company. Make it about how much value you contribute. Don't get into a comparison game where you don't have all the information. If you believe you deserve the raise have confidence, don't feel apologetic for asking for what you deserve.

Don't tell them you have another offer or that you are looking for other jobs. You want to give them the opportunity to do the right thing voluntary so that the feel it’s a fair deal for everyone. Forcing them into giving you a raise will hurt you there in the long term.

If you present your case and you don't get what you think is a fair raise then take the other offer. At that point the risk of moving is worth it because you are going to continue to be unhappy in your current job.

Don't worry about being perceived as a "job-hopper". This not as much of a concern as it was 10-20 years ago. Make sure you have a good explanation for each move. A few short jobs on a short resume is not a problem, as long as it doesn't become a lot of short jobs on a long resume.

*(This is based on my experiences in the non-government, non-union workplace in the United States)*